# How to add lines on either side of icon and text using html css and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get the lines on either side of the icon (top) and text(bottom) and dynamically to there width for my project?

[image]

Comment: what code have you tried?

Comment: let just say I didn't get any idea for it? Tried may codes though...

Answer (score 1):

Try something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/j736tvLq/)

I created a div with a border and two text elements inside

```
<div class="text-container">
    <span class="top-text">Top Text"</span>
    <span class="bottom-text">Bottom Text</span>
</div>
```

I positioned the text elements absolute relative to the parent div and used a background on them to overlay the border.

Comment: well, I want a transparent background for text. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will work for you.
HTML

```
<div class="box">
    <span class="top">TOP TEXT</span>
    <span class="bottom">BOTTOM TEXT</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #d00;
    min-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
.box > span.top {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #d00;
    top: -15px;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 35px);
}
.box > span.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #d00;
    bottom: -15px;
    left: calc(50% - 50px);
}
```

Comment: Well thank you for your answer but, this is not exactly what i wanted. I want with no background and border on text. #Does not work on transparent.

Comment: please update css classes `.box {
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #d00;
    min-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
.box > span.top {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    top: -15px;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 35px);
}
.box > span.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    bottom: -15px;
    left: calc(50% - 50px);
}`

Comment: Some Code You have pasted my buddy. Still not yet working. Check with body{background:red;} you'll find the error.

Answer (score 0):

with Jquery dynamic width capture.
HTML

```
<div class="box">
    <span class="top">TOP TEXT</span>
    <span class="bottom">BOTTOM TEXT</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #d00;
    min-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
.box > span.top {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #d00;
    top: -15px;
    position: absolute;
}
.box > span.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #d00;
    bottom: -15px;
}
```

jQuery

```
var getWidthTop = $('.box > .top').width() / 2;
var getWidthBottom = $('.box > .bottom').width() / 2;
$('.box > .top').css({'left':'calc(50% - ' + getWidthTop + 'px)'});
$('.box > .bottom').css({'left':'calc(50% - ' + getWidthBottom + 'px)'});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="box">
  <span class="top">
    Some TExt
  </span>
  <span class="bottom">
    Some TEXt
  </span>
</div>
```

and create some fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/tf8ajg0h/34/

Comment: #Does not work on transparent. Well thank you for your answer but, this is not exactly what i wanted. I want with no background and border on text.

Comment: Maybe this post help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202019/css-horizontal-line-on-one-side-of-text

Comment: Sorry my friend it didn't work. It's helpful but not in transparent background. Once remove the background of Text you'll come to know what I mean.